# Find all mongo db documents with timestamps less than 10 seconds

Tags: mongodb, go, timestamp, mgo

I am trying to get all mongo db documents with timestamps less than 10 seconds ago. I am not finding any. I think this is because my time format is not correct. I am not finding them querying mongo db from shell ***db.mgo.find({timestamp:{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 86400)}})*** for last 24h.

```
// FindLast 10min
func FindLast(session *mgo.Session, db, collection string) ([]Syslog, error) {
  var results []Syslog
  t := time.Now().Add(-10 * time.Second)
  c := session.DB(db).C(collection)
  err := c.Find(
    bson.M{
        "timestamp": bson.M{
            "$gt": t,         
        },
  }).All(&results)
  return results, err
}
```

If I pick one of document ***ObjectId("...").getTimestamp()*** it shows ***ISODate("2017-08-25T19:14:54Z")*** which is about 4h ahead of me so it is UTC. But even if I change to UTC in my func it still not finding any documents

```
t := time.Now().UTC().Add(-time.Duration(10)*time.Minute).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
```

Comment: What do the records in the DB look like?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a0772efd461bcedc236efa"),
    "domain" : "<141>August 25 19:14:54 dc 1",
    "receivetime" : "",
    "type" : "threat",   
    "generatetime" : "",
    "sourceip" : "152.152.152.152",
    "destinationip" : "2.2.2.2",
    "application" : "App test",    
    "destinationport" : "22222",
    "action" : "test",
    "threatcontentname" : "This is test only",
    "category" : "any",
    "severity" : "low",    
    "reportid" : ""
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But even if I change to UTC in my func it still not finding any documents

This is because there is no field `timestamp` within your document. The query syntax that you're using is equivalent to ask `select all documents where timestamp is greater than T from the collection`.

I assume that what you're meaning to do is to use the timestamp value derived from the [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) of every documents using `getTimestamp()` method. If this is the case, you can utilise [mgo/bson](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson) function [NewObjectIdWithTime()](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#NewObjectIdWithTime) see example as below:

```
currentTime := time.Now()
queryTime := currentTime.Add(-10 * time.Second)

// Generate a dummy ObjectId with a specified timestamp for querying
var oidtime = bson.NewObjectIdWithTime(queryTime)
query := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$gt": oidtime}}
err := collection.Find(query).All(&documents)
```

The above reversed your querying, instead of using time to query we utilises ObjectId to query. Otherwise you would have to fetch every document, convert their ObjectId's to timestamp and compare, which may not be as efficient.

Alternatively, depending on your use case you can add a `timestamp` value for each document using [$currentDate operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)
 to set the value of a field to the current date.